# Visual Studio: missing Shortcut: "Visual Studio Command Prompt"

Tags: visual-studio, command-prompt

Because the VS 2015 Installer was crashing all the time, I had to use the silent installation. Now I don't have the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" Shortcut in Start menu. Can I find it somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have a 'Visual Studio 2015' item in the start menu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to create the shortcuts manually as well, but they all follow the same pattern so no biggie:

```
%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86
```

Don't forget to change the execution path to: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\"`

Replace the last bit (`x86`) with the tool you want to use:

- `x86`
- `amd64`
- `arm`
- `x86_arm`
- `x86_amd64`
- `amd64_x86`
- `amd64_arm`

Comment: I tried to do a "dumpbin" command. It says it's not recognized. Can you imagine why? I'm doing this tutorial: https://wiki.videolan.org/GenerateLibFromDll/

Comment: What's your Working directory? It should either be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC` or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin`. If the file dumpbin.exe is missing in the VC\bin directory you may have to repair your VS installation.

Answer (score 2):

Visual studio command prompt is nothing but the regular command prompt where few environment variables are set by default. This variables are set in the batch script : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat . So basically to get a visual studio command prompt for a particular version, just open regular command prompt and run this batch script : C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat (Change the visual studio version based on your installed version). Voila you have got the visual studio command prompt. You can write a script to run the batch file and open cmd.exe and have a shortcut for the same.